# IBM App Center and iOS9 Issues

Tags: ios9, ibm-mobilefirst

IBM MobileFirst V7.0.0.00.20151006-0901 
WebSphere Liberty 8.5.5.5 IBM Java 7 
We installed MFP Server and to configure SSL, we got SSL Certificates in .p12 format.
I updated server.xml

```xml
<ssl id="SSL" keyStoreRef="SSLKeyStore" clientAuthenticationSupported="false" sslProtocol="TLSV1.2" />
<keystore id="SSLKeyStore" location="C:/IBM/SSLConfig/appkeystore.p12" type="PKCS12" password="mypassword" />
```

To support iOS9, not sure whether I need to include "enabledCiphers" ? 
If so how to get those supported list of ciphers, its an wildcard certificate.

After SSL configuration, I am able to download application from IBM AppCenter in iOS8 devices but with iOS9 getting

> Connection failed.Check your connection details (An SSL error has occurred and a secure connection to the server cannot be made.).

And I don't see any logs. When i enable installer option and then i can directly download app in iOS9 and app works fine. Getting confused what I am missing here. Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

Your SSL configuration in the server.xml looks not correct. 
It should be

```
<ssl id="defaultSSLConfig" keyStoreRef="SSLKeyStore" clientAuthenticationSupported="false" sslProtocol="TLSV1.2" />
```

or

```
<sslDefault sslRef="SSL" />
<ssl id="SSL" keyStoreRef="SSLKeyStore" clientAuthenticationSupported="false" sslProtocol="TLSV1.2" />
```

Comment: I configured as per your second approach. '<sslDefault sslRef="SSL" />
<ssl id="SSL" keyStoreRef="SSLKeyStore" clientAuthenticationSupported="false" sslProtocol="TLSV1.2" />'
SSL Configuration is fine because it works fine with Android, but IBM App Center for iOS not working

Comment: The following blog describes configuring ATS for iOS 9:
https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/2015/09/07/preparing-ibm-mobilefirst-platform-server-app-transport-security-ios-9/

Comment: Thanks Vivin, already i am following that link. To test in iOS9 , i updated NSAllowsArbitraryLoads to true & NSForwardSecrecy to false. And after that able to download an it works fine.  But not sure when we publish to AppStore will they accept with these settings ? Still trying to configure cipherlist with forward secrecy.